# Show tilting measure is martingale

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

I am doing an exercise regarding the Girsanov theorem, $B_t$ is standard brownian motion. I already find that
$$M_t=\exp(Y_t)\quad Y_t=\int_{0}^{t}-2mB_sdB_s-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t}4m^2B_s^2ds   $$
$dM_t=(-2mB_t)M_tdB_t$, $M_t$ is already a local martingale. I need to further show that $M_t$ is actually a martingale, there are two ways(based on my knowledge) to show martingale. If we can show any of following:

1. $\mathbb{E}\left[M_{t}\right]=1$
2. $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp \left\{\frac{\langle Y\rangle_{t}}{2}\right\}\right]<\infty$

I want to try second way, we need to show
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp \left\{\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}4m^2B_s^2ds\right\}\right]<\infty$$

But I don't know how to proceed, can anybody help?

Comment: Why do you know $M$ is a martingale?  Have you seen a place where they say so?

Comment: Could it be a typo in your equation and the Brownian motion in the integrand is a different and independent B.M from the one in the integrator?

Comment: First, any process $X_t$ satisfy SDE $dX_t=A_tX_tdB_t$ is a local martingale, where $A_t$ is adapted process. There is no problem that $A_t=B_t$

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, you may want to give more background about the original problem. Where is your integrand $-2mB_s$ coming from?

Comment: The original problem is that $M_{t}=\exp \left(Y_{t}\right) \quad Y_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}A_{s} d B_{s}-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} A_{s}^{2} d s$, given different $A_t$,  need to prove $M_t$ is martingale. This subproblem is to let $A_t=-2mB_t,m>0$, prove $M_t$ is a martingale. I think it is enough to show case $A_t=B_t$. constant is not important

Comment: is the process $A$ independent of the Brownian motion in the original problem? (this is a key aspect to show that $M$ is a martingale)

Comment: we only have $A_t $ is $\mathcal{F}_{t}-$measurable, the $B_s$ in integrand is same as that in $dB_s$

Comment: if $A$ is independent of the B.M, then I know how to prove that $M$ is a martingale. If $A$ is not independent, I have no idea and I doubt that the result is true  (and obviously $A_t=-2mB_t,$  is not independent of $B_t$)

Comment: The problem, imo, is well-defined as it is written. My question is, since it says $-m$, is perhaps $m>0$ an hyphotesis? In this case, I think the Novikov criterion you wrote won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it using Kazamaki's criterion.

We want to show that for any $t>0$, $\mathbb{E}[e^{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t-2mB_sdB_s}]<+\infty$.

This is equivalent to $\mathbb{E}[e^{-m\int_0^tB_sdB_s}] < +\infty$.

It should be easy to conclude for $m>0$ using that $\int_0^t B_sdB_s = \frac{B_t^2-t}{2}$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\int_0^t-2mB_sdB_s=\int_0^t 4m^2B_s^2ds$?

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I wrote.